# Prevent Users from Navigating Hidden Authors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hide, url-routing

I have an index page that hides/shows different Authors by using a boolean. The problem that I am having is that signed in users can still access hidden authors and their books through the URL.

**How can I prevent current users from navigating to hidden Authors and their corresponding Books through the URL? Is there a way to redirect them back to Authors Page if author is hidden?**

Currently, I have used the Controllers & a boolean value to help hide/show Authors or Books from signed in users. Can someone please point me in the right direction. Here is my Code.

**MODELS**

```
class Author < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :photo

  has_many :books

end

class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :author_id, :title, :photo

  belongs_to :author

end
```

**CONTROLLERS**

```
class AuthorsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :signed_in_user, only: [:index]
  before_filter :admin_user, only: [:edit, :update, :destroy, :new, :show]

  respond_to :html, :js

  ###Only displays unhidden authors to non admin users.  

  def index
    if current_user.admin?
      @authors = Author.all(:order => "created_at")
    else
      @authors = Author.where(:display => true).all(:order => "created_at")
    end
  end

  private

    def signed_in_user
      unless signed_in?
        store_location
        redirect_to (root_path), notice: "Please sign in."
      end
    end

    def admin_user
      redirect_to(root_path) unless current_user.admin?
    end
end

class BooksController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :signed_in_user, only: [:index]
  before_filter :admin_user, only: [:edit, :update, :destroy, :new, :show]
  before_filter :get_author

  respond_to :html, :js

  def get_author
    @author = Author.find(params[:author_id])
  end

  def index
    @books = @author.books
  end

  private

    def signed_in_user
      unless signed_in?
        store_location
        redirect_to (root_path), notice: "Please sign in."
      end
    end

    def admin_user
      redirect_to(root_path) unless current_user.admin?
    end
end
```

**VIEWS**

```
Authors index.html.erb

<% @authors.each do |author| %>

  <%= link_to (image_tag author.photo(:medium)), 
    url_for(author_books_path(author)),
    class: "img-rounded" %>

<% end %>

### How Can I prevent Users from accessing Hidden Author's Books (Index Page)
Books index.html.erb

  <% @books.each do |book| %>
    <%= image_tag book.photo(:medium) %>
    <%= book.name %>
  <% end %>
```

**ROUTES**

```
resources :authors do
  resources :books
end
```

**SCHEMA**

```
create_table "authors", :force => true do |t|
  t.string   "name"
  t.boolean  "display",             :default => false
  t.datetime "created_at",                             :null => false
  t.datetime "updated_at",                             :null => false
  t.string   "photo_file_name"
  t.string   "photo_content_type"
  t.integer  "photo_file_size"
  t.datetime "photo_updated_at"
end

create_table "books", :force => true do |t|
  t.integer  "author_id"
  t.string   "title"
  t.datetime "created_at",          :null => false
  t.datetime "updated_at",          :null => false
  t.string   "photo_file_name"
  t.string   "photo_content_type"
  t.integer  "photo_file_size"
  t.datetime "photo_updated_at"
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the Authors#show Controller, you can write for example --

```
Authors#Show
def show
 @author = Author.find(params[:id])
 redirect_to root_url unless @author.display
end
```

In this case, when a user visits any author's url, it will check to see if that author's display attribute is true or not, and redirect accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

Use a proper authorization model, such as [CanCan](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan).

The key part (for CanCan) would be in authorizing based on user roles:

```
if user.role == admin
  can :manage, :all
else 
  can :read, Author, display: true
end
```

There is a helpful [RailsCast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/192-authorization-with-cancan) to step you through using CanCan for authorization.

Other options exist, such as [Declarative Authorization](https://github.com/stffn/declarative_authorization), or you can roll your own.

Answer (score 2):

```
Use a proper authorization model, such as CanCan.
```

Personally, I'm not sure I agree with this, at least given the scope of the issue you seem to be trying to solve. However, your comments in `/app/views/books/index.html.erb` seem to indicate you wanted to place some logic in your view file. Do *NOT* do this. Following proper MVC architecture, what you're attempting to do falls under the category of business logic. As such, the code that controls this should be in your controllers.

In your `/app/controllers/book_controller.rb` file, change the action for an Author's books page to redirect back to the author depending on the author's attributes. Something like this: (not sure what the exact path would be):

```
def index  
  # Redirect if author is set to hidden
  if !@author.display
    redirect_to author_path
  else  
    @books = @author.books  
  end  
end
```